# asp.net control 2 textbox with ajax slider extender control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Suppose I have 2 textboxes which can be controlled by ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender. One textbox bounded with slider that's fine. Now I need some customization that If I increase slider then first textbox value gets decrease & vice versa. Sorry I know whether I am able to post my question correctly. But I want to make something like shown in below ref link(https://360rewards.standardchartered.com/in/award/detail/amazon-all-new-kindle-paperwhite-2015-wifi-3g/58361).

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" Minimum="5" Maximum="50" TargetControlID="txt1" BoundControlID="txt2" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with javascript
something like this

```
var firstTb = document.getElementById("txt1");
    firstTb.addEventListener("change", changeValue);

    function changeValue() {
        var max = 100;//your max slider value
        var current = parseInt(firstTb.value);

        document.getElementById("txt3").value = (max - current)/*here your calculations */;
    }
```

Ok, i think, i found a solution for dynamic changing
add BehaviorID="sliderBehavior" to your slider extender and in js

```
function pageLoad(sender, e) {
        var slider = $find('sliderBehavior');
        slider.add_valueChanged(onValueChanged);
    }

    function onValueChanged(sender, e) {
        var max = 100;
        var current = parseInt(sender._value);
        document.getElementById("txt3").value = (max - current)/*calculations*/;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but can it be also done on real time? Like as I scroll values gets reflected. Currently it does work once I finish sliding